# Sequential discontinuity verification

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that the function below is not continuous by the sequential definition of continuity, I did a tentative approach but I have never done continuity by the sequential definition so I am not sure if it is correct.

**Questions:**

> Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
>
> $f(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ if $x$ is different from $0$
>
> $f(x) = a$ if $x = 0$

**My proof:**

Regardless of the value of $a$, the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$ when $n$ goes to infinity, however $f(x_n) = \sin(n)$ and therefore the sequence $f(x_n)$ does not converge when $n$ goes to infinity, so we are done.

Is this correct? If so, can it be improved.  If it is not correct, please point out where I slipped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct but you should say that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin n$ does not exist hence $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(0) = a$. Thus $f$ is not continuous at $x = 0$. You could take $x_n = \dfrac{1}{(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}$ if $a \neq 1$ and $x_n = \dfrac{1}{(4n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}}$ if $a \neq -1$ then it is not the case that $f(x_n) \to f(0) = a$ .

Comment: I did not understand the second part of your answer, I am taking x_n = 1/n. Does the part below mean that I should have taken another x_n ? You could take $x_n = \dfrac{1}{(4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}$ if $a \neq 1$ and $x_n = \dfrac{1}{(4n-1)\frac{\pi}{2}}$ if $a \neq -1$ then it is not the case that $f(x_n) \to f(0) = a$ .

Comment: Yes, it’s another choice for $x_n$.